# ¿Cómo conectarse a Firebird utilizando Java?

Tags: java, firebird

Quiero conectar un programa de java con una base de datos de Firebird con extensión ".fire" ¿Cómo podría hacerlo? Ando un poco perdido con las conexiones con bases de datos.

Answer (score 1):

Pues necesitas un [JDBC para Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/jdbc-driver/)

Ya que lo instales y lo pongas en tu projecto entonces ya puedes usar

`org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver`

Ejemplo usando  [Jaybird 2.1](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/java/faq.html#pure-java-default)

```
import java.sql.*;
public class HelloServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class.forName("org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:firebirdsql:localhost/3050:c:/db/employee.fdb","SYSDBA", "masterkey");
    }
}
```

Solo tienes que cambiar tus datos en  `getConnection`

Más documentación para [Jaybird 2.1](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/drivers-documentation/)

Comment: Gracias. Estaba haciendo algo parecido pero el verdadero problema era que el servidor de Firebird no me arrancaba y cada vez que lo intentaba mediante el panel de control (como lo explican en algunas webs que encontré) me aparecían inhabilitadas las opciones de arranque.

Finalmente lo conseguí accediendo mediante los servicios de Windows (Windows 10) y forzando el arranque del servidor desde ahí.

Iba a editar tu respuesta para explicar esto, pero seguramente tú lo puedas añadir mejor que yo (es la primera vez que uso stackoverflow y no sé dar el formato correcto aun).

Muchas gracias!

Comment: No hay problema.